# Excel Object Required Error when Running Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro such that if a given cell in the range L2:L318 contains a particular value, the cell in column H in the same row is modified to a new string.

At this point, I have what appears to be something passable, but I get an 'Object Required' error when it runs. My code is as follows:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Worksheet.Range("L2:L318")
Dim i As Integer


For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value("902.4") Then
    i = i + 1
    Sheet.Cells(8, i).Value = "Text"


    Else
    i = i + 1

    End If

Next cell


End Sub
```

I'll admit I haven't the slightest idea what I'm doing, and there's at least a moderate chance my code is complete nonsense. Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated - I've literally never touched Excel macros before today!

Comment: You need to `Set rng =`.

Comment: @BrianMStafford you're correct - I missed that! That being said, it still returns the 'Object Required' error.

Comment: Where is `Worksheet` defined?  Is that supposed to be `ActiveSheet`? Same with `Sheet`.  I'd suggest putting `Option Explicit` at the top of the module and correcting all the errors it flags.

Comment: set rng = Worksheets("your worksheet name").Range("L2:L318")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great start!  You've got a few things off, but for the most part you weren't too far off.  Keep in mind there are a *ton* of different ways to approach this, but since you're learning, I took your approach and made it work.  See if this gets you close to what you're after:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Range("L2:L318")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = 902.4 Then Cells(cell.Row, 8).Value = "Text"
Next cell

End Sub
```

Take a look at what I posted and see if you can make heads or tails of it.  As you can see, it's not too far off what you had, just cleaned up a little and fixed the syntax.

Keep in mind, this macro will run on the currently active sheet.  If you need it to run on a specific sheet, you'll have to qualify your range reference a bit better...something like: Worksheets("your worksheet name").Range("L2:L318")

Comment: Oh my gosh it works. I've been staring at this for an hour - you're a life saver. Correct me if I'm wrong - doesn't this effectively render i pointless?

Comment: @PaigeJaclyn yep, that's why I took it out :).  If it helped, feel free to up vote and /or accept it as a solution so others know that it worked.